# Flask Uploads Photo class

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, image-uploading, flask-uploads

Trying to write a website that will allow users to upload photos, and so far, I've been using the Flask-Uploads library (docs [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/))

Used in the example in the docs is a class `Photo` that seems fairly critical:

```
    rec = Photo(filename=filename, user=g.user.id)
    rec.store()
    ...
    photo = Photo.load(id)
```

Problem being that the name `Photo` doesn't exist in `flask.ext.uploads` and I'm not sure where to upload it from.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

`Photo` is a model class that you'd need to define. If you take a look at the [example application](https://bitbucket.org/leafstorm/flask-uploads/src/440e06b851d24811d20f8e06a8eaf5c5bf58c241/example/photolog.py?at=default) you'll see a class named `Post`.

```
post = Post(title=title, caption=caption, filename=filename)
post.id = unique_id()
post.store()
```

This particular example was made using [Flask-CouchDB](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-CouchDB/), but you can use any data store you'd like. You'll just need to replace the lines that save the `Photo` or `Post` with however you save references to uploaded files in your application.